# ¿Cómo puedo juntar cada 2 elementos de una lista?

Tags: python

Tengo esta lista que son los resultados de los nodos que se visitaran en un problema:

```
[1, 279, 2, 278, 277, 3, 276, 1]
```

¿Como puedo hacer que la lista quede de esta manera?.

```
[(1,279), (279,2), (2,278), (278,277), (277,3), (3,276), (276,1)]
```

¿Por que de esa manera? -> Porque esas son las ubicaciones de los arcos que se visitaran dentro de una grafica. Para entenderlo mejor, este es mi diccionario **(sin todos los valores porque son 280 nodos)**.

```
Este diccionario tiene como "keys" la interaccion de un nodo con todos los demas y asi 
sucesivamente para el siguiente nodo, el "value" de cada "key" es la distancia entre 
esos 2 nodos.

{(0, 1): 63.245553203367585,
 (0, 2): 44.94441010848846,
 (0, 3): 29.120439557122072,
 (0, 4): 29.120439557122072,
 (0, 5): 19.697715603592208,
 (0, 6): 21.540659228538015
 asi sucesivamente hasta
 (279,278): 20.396078054371138
}
```

Una vez obteniendo esta lista:

```
[(1,279), (279,2), (2,278), (278,277), (277,3), (3,276), (276,275), (275,1)]
```

Buscare cada valor dentro del diccionario para imprimir y sumar las distancias. Esa es mi idea de encontrar las distancias dentro del diccionario y despues sumarlas.

Comment: ¿Por qué los últimos resultados esperado son `(3,276), (276,275), (275,1)`? ¿No debería ser `(3,276), (276,1)`?

Comment: Si, una disculpa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solución de una sola línea:

```
list(zip(lista, lista[1:]))
```

Explicación:

- `zip()` acepta varios iterables como parámetro (por ejemplo `zip(l1, l2, l3)`) y retorna un iterador. Cada vez que se itera sobre el iterador retornado por `zip()`, éste devuelve una tupla formada por un elemento de cada uno de los iterables que se le pasó como parámetro (es decir, la primera iteración dará la tupla `(l1[0], l2[0], l3[0])`, la siguiente iteración dará `(l1[1], l2[1], l3[1])`, etc) hasta que uno de los iterables se agote, en cuyo caso termina.
- En nuestro caso le he pasado como parámetros `lista` y `lista[1:]`. El primero es tu lista completa. El segundo es tu lista, excepto el primer elemento. De este modo, en la primera iteración devolverá una tupla con el primer elemento de `lista`, junto con el primer elemento de `lista[1:]` (que es el segundo elemento de la lista original). Así hasta que `lista[1:]`, que es más corta, se agote.
- Envolviendo todo en `list()`, hacemos que python itere sobre el iterador devuelto por `zip()` y construya una lista con el resultado.

Ejemplo:

```
>>> lista = [1, 279, 2, 278, 277, 3, 276, 1]
>>> list(zip(lista, lista[1:]))
[(1, 279), (279, 2), (2, 278), (278, 277), (277, 3), (3, 276), (276, 1)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

#### Forma iterativa clásica:

```
lista = [1, 279, 2, 278, 277, 3, 276, 1]

nueva_lista = list()
for i in range(len(lista)-1):
  tupla = (lista[i], lista[i+1])
  nueva_lista.append(tupla)

print(nueva_lista)
[(1, 279), (279, 2), (2, 278), (278, 277), (277, 3), (3, 276), (276, 1)]
```

- Iteramos por cada elemento hasta `len(list) - 1`
- por cada elemento generamos una tupla, con el mismo elemento, más el siguiente.

#### Comprensión de listas

```
nueva_lista = [(lista[i], lista[i+1]) for i in range(len(lista)-1)]
print(nueva_lista)
[(1, 279), (279, 2), (2, 278), (278, 277), (277, 3), (3, 276), (276, 1)]
```

Es una forma mucho más compacta de "comprender" la manera iterativa anterior